# Is there any easy way to redirect to session expire page after session timeout without redirecting to formauthentication  loginUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I know we have form authentication to set loginUrl and when session expires it automatically redirects to this URL.

I have a requirement where I have to show different page on session expiration not login.aspx

I was searching for it but did not find any suitable easy to implement solutions.

I can't prefer to change to existing deployed site code behind and client want to implement this new SessionExpired.aspx page

I read http://www.schnieds.com/2009/07/aspnet-session-expiration-redirect.html , they have nice solution but I have to make change in .cs file that I don't want to do at least until I get any easy solution.

Is there any easy way to redirect to session expire page after form authentication timeout without redirecting to loginUrl?

Comment: What kind of a client is that? He wants you to only add a `SessionExpired.aspx` and by some magic the application start redirecting to this new page without touching to the application code. That's like asking to deliver a new car in his garage without wiring the money into the bank account.

Comment: Thats the first preference he is asking for. If no other way offcourse we will change the .cs and deployed it after proper testing. I just want to know if there is any way to avoid it. Don't you think formauthentication should provide somthing like this.

Comment: No, there's no way. Just adding an ASPX page without touching to the rest of the application code won't have much effect.

Comment: if no ASPX. HTML or javascript is fine

Answer (score 3):

After creating the `SessionExpired.aspx` page you need to add just a single line in head section in aspx (not .cs) of your pages. (I hope you have implemented master pages, so it will be added only at the master page)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
   content="1201;url=http://yourdomain.com/SessionExpired.aspx" />
```

This line will automatically redirects the browser to SessionExpired page after 1201 seconds, i.e. 20 minutes

Comment: this sounds perfect solution.